# What happens with checked luggage with an airport change?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airport-transfer, jfk, lga

I'm considering two Miami - Zürich flights, which connect at New York. Both start MIA - JFK, but one continues with JFK - ZRH and the other with LGA - ZRH.

If I check my luggage at Miami, and take a cab from JFK to LGA, will I have to carry my bags and re-check them at LGA, or does the airline do this?

The cost difference (two people) is ~120 USD total. How much is the taxi, normally? Is an airport change worth the hassle?

Comment: As a general rule, if you have to change airports, the transfer is your responsibility, and you have to take your luggage with you

Comment: Much better question is how did you come up with a direct flight from LaGuardia to Zurich?

Comment: Definitely not worth the hassle, I'd say.

Comment: @Karlson: Indeed.  As far as I know, LaGuardia has no overseas flights at all.  (In any case, it would only be allowed to operate on Saturdays!)  I think maybe the OP has got it backwards.

Comment: @NateEldredge Technically it may be possible with Boeing 757 but I don't see any departures across the Pond.  Why Saturday?

Comment: @Karlson: LGA has a "perimeter rule": all nonstop flights must be under 1500 miles, except on Saturdays.  There is a "grandfather clause" exception for Denver.  I believe the intention was to move all long-haul flying to JFK and EWR.

Comment: @NateEldredge Makes sense.

Comment: @Karlson, MIA - JFK/LGA - ZRH was one of the options AA listed for my flight (it actually begins in ZRH, goes somewhere else, and then that part, but should it make any difference?)

Comment: @ggambett I can't generate multi airport transfer itinerary from AA.  You can transfer in LGA to another domestic flight and then to an international otherwise it's still 2 different itineraries.  Unless the site you're looking at only means that JFK/LGA/EWR is a connection visa New York city.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the life of me I could not come up with a single itinerary that will fly Miami to JFK then LaGuardia to Zurich.

So if this is the case there are 2 different itineraries in play then you will need to collect your luggage and re-check it at the next airport to your final destination, which has been discussed in many forms on this site already:

- [Re-checking luggage at connecting airports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8314/re-checking-luggage-at-connecting-airports)
- [Do I need to pick up my luggage and re-check it between Washington, DC and and Shanghai?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16476/do-i-need-to-pick-up-my-luggage-and-re-check-it-between-washington-dc-and-and-s?rq=1)
- [Is it possible to buy a ticket where the luggage cannot be checked to the final destination?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17441/is-it-possible-to-buy-a-ticket-where-the-luggage-cannot-be-checked-to-the-final?rq=1)

So if you need to transfer from airport to airport you will have to collect your luggage.  Carry it to the Taxi $35-$50 + tip and at least an hour of your time then checking it for your next connection and so on.

Personally while $70 is not chump change is it really worth about 2 hours of your time?

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

Just found a way to create a connection with an airport transfer.  There is also a rule listed in [US-Canada Domestic Rules 205AA A.3.e](https://www.aa.com/i18n/Tariffs/CGR1.htm) which states:

> Baggage will not be checked beyond a point at which the passenger is to transfer to a connecting flight, if that flight is scheduled to depart from an airport different from the one at which the passenger is scheduled to arrive.

So you will definitely have to pick it up.  Hump it to a taxi then check it back in at the other airport and continue. Personally I prefer convenience.

Comment: It *is* a single itinerary, though :) ZRH - MVD - MIA - ZRH, staying ~1 week in MVD and MIA. I get the airport change through LGA (or EWR) in the MIA - ZRH part.

Comment: @ggambett That's not a single itinerary/reservation that's multiple itineraries as far as airline is concerned.  If you bought it as one it doesn't imply a single Reservation for the airline.  If you Look at your reservation on the airline site it will list your connecting airports.

Comment: Maybe I have the wrong idea of what a Reservation and an Itinerary are. I found this airport change when booking a multi-city trip in the AA website.

Comment: @ggambett Now it makes more sense I am amending my answer as well.

Answer (score 6):

When you fly from the US to Europe, the bag could be checked through to its final destination except if you have an airport change e.g. from LGA to JFK or EWR. If you have an airport change, then the baggage label / ticket is not for the final destination.

It is generally not worth doing an airport change. First you have to pick your luggage up and then you are at the mercy of traffic and other problems.

When you fly from Europe back to the US, you'd have to pick your luggage up anyway in the first port of arrival to then recheck it. The label on the bag would already be the right one to Miami in your case except if you change airports (e.g. from JFK to LGA).

Comment: *When you fly from the US to Europe, the bag is always checked through to its final destination* - Not necessarily true even without the airport change.

Comment: Yes good point, I should say that the bag can be checked through and it's usually the case